# Does the output of pattern-file grep depend on the order of patterns in the pattern-file?

Tags: grep, osx, regular-expression

I am running Mac OS X, so UNIX and I am getting what seems to me a strange result.

I have two pattern files:

**file1**

```
PAMR1
PAM
```

**file2**

```
PAM
PAMR1
```

Running `grep -w -f my_file results.csv` gives different results for the different files.

`grep -w -f file2 file2` returns:

```
PAM
```

But `grep -w -f file1 file2` returns:

```
PAM
PAMR1
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Why doesn't the first case return both patterns? Only one pattern is matched and clearly `PAMR1` matches itself.

Comment: what is the unix equivalent? `-A` is an illegal option on mac. there are no carriage returns (`cat -v`)

Comment: just $ at the end of each line, is it possible to update grep?

Comment: I can't see any reason why you would get only `PAM` for given input files for `grep -w -f file2 file2` command... file2 has two words and you are giving both words as search input

Comment: I tried this on a linux system and got the expected result... So there must be a bug with my version: `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`

Comment: yeah that could be it... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259484/grep-bsd-grep-2-5-1-freebsd-on-mac-os-10-8-line-regexp-mode-not-working-with-o

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45660691/4957508

Comment: @Jeff Schaller: OK, that stackoverflow.com/45660691 question has been deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of grep doesn't depend on the order of the patterns in a file, as long as you ask grep to output whole lines and not to identify the part of the line that matches (e.g. with the `-o` or `--color` option).

Unless there's a bug in grep, that is. As identified by [Sundeep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/109046/sundeep) in comments, there's a bug in grep on FreeBSD/macOS that makes it miss a pattern when another pattern earlier in the file is a prefix of it.